How to interpret Snyk Fixed In Go versions that aren't released?
I ran the Snyk security scanner to find vulnerabilities in a Go project, which it did, but it seems like the fixed versions reported don't exist, or are not released, yet.
Here are two examples that seem to report fixes in Go 1.56.3, 1.57.1, and 1.58.3, as well as Go 3.24.1, while the highest version at go.dev/dl is 1.23.3.
What do these release numbers refer to, and how would one remediate these findings?
Snyk reports fixes in Go 1.56.3, 1.57.1, and 1.58.3

Snyk reports fixes in Go 3.24.1


Not sure why it's displaying that way, maybe if you click "show more detail", but for the first one at least you need to upgrade google.golang.org/grpc to version 1.56.3, 1.57.1, 1.58.3 or higher (see https://security.snyk.io/vuln/SNYK-GOLANG-GOOGLEGOLANGORGGRPC-5953328).
I'm sure the second one is similar - it's for a specific package, not for the go version itself (e.g. it could be https://security.snyk.io/vuln/SNYK-GOLANG-GOTHETHINGSNETWORKLORAWANSTACKV3PKGWEBUIACCOUNTVIEWSLOGIN-7653732)
